# lambda in for loop only takes last value

Tags: python, lambda

I have the code

```
options=["INFO", "WARNING", "DEBUG"]

for i in range(len(options)):
    option=options[i]
    __cMenu.add_command(
        label="{}".format(option), 
        command=lambda: self.filter_records(column, option)
   )
```

which creates and saves several lambdas that should capture different values of the local variable `option`. However, when these lambdas get used, they all behave as though `options` was set to `"DEBUG"`, the last value it takes on in the loop.

I am guessing this has something to do with the garbage collection in that only the last option remains, but I cannot figure out how to avoid this.

Comment: The underlying issue as well as solution is detailed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Please read about [minimal examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Without reading your code, I believe you have run into a well known issue addressed in previous questions and answers that needs 2 lines to illustrate.  Names in function bodies are evaluated when the function is executed.

```
funcs = [lambda: i for i in range(3)]
for f in funcs: print(f())
```

prints '2' 3 times because the 3 functions are identical and the 'i' in each is not evaluated until the call, when i == 2.  However,

```
funcs = [lambda i=i:i for i in range(3)]
for f in funcs: print(f())
```

makes three different functions, each with a different captured value, so 0, 1, and 2 are printed.  In your statement

```
__cMenu.add_command(label="{}".format(option),
    command=lambda: self.filter_records(column, option))
```

add `option=option` before `:` to capture the different values of `option`.  You might want to rewrite as

```
lambda opt=option: self.filter_records(column, opt)
```

to differentiate the loop variable from the function parameter.  If `column` changed within the loop, it would need the same treatment.

Answer (score 22):

Closures in Python capture variables, not values. For example consider:

```
def f():
    x = 1
    g = lambda : x
    x = 2
    return g()
```

What do you expect the result of calling `f()` to be? The correct answer is 2, because the lambda `f` captured the **variable** `x`, not its value 1 at the time of creation.

Now if for example we write:

```
L = [(lambda : i) for i in range(10)]
```

we created a list of 10 different lambdas, but all of them captured the same variable `i`, thus calling `L[3]()` the result will be 9 because the value of variable `i` at the end of the iteration was `9` (in Python a comprehension doesn't create a new binding for each iteration; it just keeps updating the same binding).

A "trick" that can be seen often in Python when capturing the **value** is the desired semantic is to use default arguments. In Python, differently from say C++, default value expressions are evaluated at function definition time (i.e. when the lambda is created) and not when the function is invoked. So in code like:

```
L = [(lambda j=i: j) for i in range(10)]
```

we're declaring a parameter `j` and setting as default the current value of `i` at the time the lambda was created. This means that when calling e.g. `L[3]()` the result will be 3 this time because of the default value of the "hidden" parameter (calling `L[3](42)` will return 42 of course).

More often you see the sightly more confusing form

```
lambda i=i: ...
```

where the "hidden" parameter has the same name as the variable of which we want to capture the value of.

Answer (score -1):

I know I am late, but I found a messy workaround which gets the job done (tested in Python 3.7)

If you use a double lambda (like I said, very messy) you can preserve the value, like so:

Step 1: Create the nested lambda statement:

```py
send_param = lambda val: lambda: print(val)
```

Step 2: Use the lambda statement:

```py
send_param(i)
```

The `send_param` method returns the inner most lambda (`lambda: print(val)`) without executing the statement, until you call the result of `send_param` which takes no arguments, for example:

```py
a = send_param(i)
a()
```

Only the second line will execute the `print` statement.

Comment: Function calls in Python are typically slow, whereas variable assignment, as used by the other solutions, is typically fast. Assigning a temporary variable inside the loop is also simpler than nested lambdas and double indirection.

Comment: OK, maybe it's slow, but it still provides a solution and just the fact that it isn't *as* good as the other solutions doesn't mean that it should be downvoted. It is properly explained and it addresses the question. There is nothing wrong with it. +1