# Behavior of lists of lambda expression

Tags: python, list, lambda

I created a list of lambda functions, and later called these functions in the list.
However, they call the very last lambda only.
I cannot see what the lambda is, in order to check it, since all it returns is a signature like `<function <lambda> at 0x7f6da69b89e0>`.
Unless Python doesn't allow a list consisting of lambda functions?
I am using Python 3.

```
quxs = [2, 3, 5, 7]
funs = []
for qux in quxs:
    funs.append (lambda x, y: x + y * qux)
for fun in funs:
    print (fun (1, 4))

# expected: 9, 13, 21, 29
# result: 29, 29, 29, 29
```

Comment: change to `funs.append(lambda x, y, p=qux: x + y * p)`

Comment: The question was already answered but I added what in my opinion is a better explanation of what happens here https://stackoverflow.com/a/57736125/320726 (as an answer to the first listed as duplicate).

Comment: @6502 That's indeed a good answer!