# PyQt5 designer gui and iterate/loop over QPushButton

Tags: python-3.x, loops, pyqt5, qpushbutton

Hi I have a GUI with 26 QPushButtons named A to Z, using uicload I load into my Main class

is there any way to loop over them to end up  with something

```
self.A.clicked.connect(self.foo(A))
# ..
self.Z.clicked.connect(self.foo(Z))
```

tried different ways but I end up always with either a syntax error or a

```
AttributeError: 'Main' object has no attribute 'button' (button = i for i in letters)
```

of course using:

just

```
self.A.clicked.connect(self.foo(A))
```

it works but not the loop (like for i in list, where list is names of the button A,B,C  ... Z

Comment: use `for letter in "ABCDE":` `getattr(self, letter).clicked.connect(lambda checked, letter=letter: foo(letter))`

Comment: Hi thank yhou again, thats what I was looking for, kind of understood the getattr(self, letter), somehow I'll figure out the the need of lambda too. But lambda checked and the need of letter=letter is quite difficult to me have you got some reading about it, other than the two links above ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983980/lambda-in-for-loop-only-takes-last-value this one helped too