# Problem creating a simple tkinter GUI that displays names of text files from a folder and their contents when clicked

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I have been trying to develop a GUI for my python based voice assistant. The following is a snippet of the code that I am having problem with.
What I want to do is display the name of text files from a folder and display their contents in the same window when the user clicks on one of the file names.

```
from tkinter import *
import os

menu_color = "#2c2b34"
frame_color = "#28262e"
font_color = "#06dff5"

ss_f_button = []
note_f_button = []
note_text = None

def note_window():  #To operate Note Window
    global note_f_button
    path = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "Notes/")
    note_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path)]
    note_f_button = []
    if len(note_files)>0:
        y=60
        for i in range(len(note_files)):
            note_f_button.append(Button(root, bg=frame_color, fg=font_color, activebackground=frame_color, activeforeground=font_color, bd ="0", text=note_files[i], font=("Helvetica Neue Bold", "10"), cursor="hand2", command=lambda: open_note(note_files[i])))
            note_f_button[i].place(x=55, y=y)
            y+=40
    root.update()

def open_note(f_name): #To operate Note Window
    global note_text
    if note_text != None:
        note_text.place_forget()
        note_text = None
    path = os.path.join(sys.path[0], "Notes/")
    with open(f"{path}{f_name}", "r") as file:
        note_text = file.read()
    note_text = Label(root, text=note_text, bg=frame_color, fg=font_color, font=("Helvetica Neue Bold", "11"))
    note_text.place(x=340, y=60)
    root.update()


root = Tk()
root.title("TEST")
root.geometry("706x462")

note_window()


root.update()
root.mainloop()
```

Here is the output: 
[image]
You would understand it best if you run it yourself!! *If you try this code, be sure to change the font style as Helvetica may not be installed in your system!!*

The problem I am facing is that both the files show the same text when clicked, or more specifically, **both of them show the same text from the test.txt file.**
Can anyone please provide a way to do what I am trying to achieve and also point out where I am doing it wrong.
I am using Python 3.8.3.

Comment: See [lambda-in-for-loop-only-takes-last-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983980/lambda-in-for-loop-only-takes-last-value)

Comment: @acw1668 Thank you for your quick and efficient reply!! Really appreciate it!