# PyQt Signals on Auto-Generated Widgets

Tags: python, pyqt5

```
    def spawnReps(self):
        db = SECLIB.connectToDB()
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("Select * from Reps")
        for x in cursor:
            thisWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            thisLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(thisWidget)
            thisRepNumLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(text="Rep Num:")
            thisRepNum = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            thisRepNum.setText(x[0])
            thisLayout.addWidget(thisRepNumLabel)
            thisLayout.addWidget(thisRepNum)
            thisRepFnameLabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(text="First Name:")
            thisRepFname = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
            thisRepFname.setText(x[1])
            thisRepFname.editingFinished.connect(lambda: self.repUpdated(thisRepFname.text()))

    def repUpdated(self, object):
        print(object)
```

So this function generates a sheet to view all of our agents, I want to make each of them directly editable in line, but when I connect the function in the for loop every edit returns the very last instance that was created. What would i need to do for it to return the Instance that was actually changed??

Comment: use `thisRepFname.editingFinished.connect(lambda le=thisRepFname: self.repUpdated(le.text()))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [lambda in for loop only takes last value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33983980)

Comment: eyllanesc Thanks!