# Why does tkinter mix bindings of different widgets when creating the widgets in a loop but not when creating them separately?

Tags: python, tkinter

Tkinter mixes bindings of different widgets when the widgets are created in a loop, but when the widgets are created separately, the bindings are correct. I cannot figure out why this is the case.

### Wrong bindings

Here's a working example to reproduce the problem. Two widgets (images that should work as buttons that are highlighted when hovering over) are created in a loop and packed in a second loop.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


IMG_DEFAULT = 'add_default.png'
IMG_HOVER = 'add_hover.png'

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title('WRONG!')
        self.img_default = tk.PhotoImage(file=IMG_DEFAULT)
        self.img_hover = tk.PhotoImage(file=IMG_HOVER)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.buttons = []
        for i in range(2):
            button = ttk.Label(image=self.img_default)
            button.bind('<Button-1>', ...)  # Do something
            button.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: button.config(image=self.img_hover))
            button.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: button.config(image=self.img_default))
            self.buttons.append(button)

    def pack_widgets(self):
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.pack(padx=100, pady=10)

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

As can be seen from the image below, the bindings are wrong: when I hover over the upper button, the lower button is highlighted.

[image]

### Correct binding

When the widgets are created outside a loop, the key bindings are correct.

```py
import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk as ttk


IMG_DEFAULT = 'add_default.png'
IMG_HOVER = 'add_hover.png'

class Application(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, master=None, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.title('RIGHT!')
        self.img_default = tk.PhotoImage(file=IMG_DEFAULT)
        self.img_hover = tk.PhotoImage(file=IMG_HOVER)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.pack_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        button1 = ttk.Label(image=self.img_default)
        button1.bind('<Button-1>', ...)   # Do something
        button1.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: button1.config(image=self.img_hover))
        button1.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: button1.config(image=self.img_default))

        button2 = ttk.Label(image=self.img_default)
        button2.bind('<Button-1>', ...)   # Do something
        button2.bind('<Enter>', lambda e: button2.config(image=self.img_hover))
        button2.bind('<Leave>', lambda e: button2.config(image=self.img_default))

        self.buttons = [button1, button2]

    def pack_widgets(self):
        for button in self.buttons:
            button.pack(padx=100, pady=10)

app = Application()
app.mainloop()
```

As can be seen from the image, now the bindings are correct: when I hover over the upper button, the upper button is highlighted and when I hover over the lower, it is highlighted.

[image]

Can anyone explain why the second case works as intended but the first does not? In my application, I have a more general use case with an unknown number of buttons. How can I get the correct bindings in place?

### EDIT

As pointed out by [Bryan Oakley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7432/bryan-oakley) in his comment, my question is a duplicate of [Tkinter assign button command in loop with lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/12646289). Both the solutions of [Henry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7519434/henry) (https://stackoverflow.com/a/66663554/12646289) and [acw1668](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5317403/acw1668) provide the solution.

Thanks a lot for your help! I have upvoted the comments and accepted Henry's answer.

Comment: Start by reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/17677649/7432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by your lambdas. When the binding is called, it uses the current value of button for config. If you made 4 buttons they'd all change the image on the last one because it is the last value of button. (I'm not sure if I've explained it very well, please look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33984811) for more detail). You need to change the lambda to

```
lambda e, b = button: b.config(...)
```

This creates a reference to the particular button so when the binding is called, the image for that button changes.

Comment: Just use `e.widget.config(...)` and don't need to use another argument.